# AngularJS: How to save variable in modal to my $scope?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, angularjs

I'm making a task management tool in AngularJS and I have a form that the user has to fill to create a new task. Here's a short version of it:

```
<div ng-controller="SubmitController">
    <!-- Form -->
    <form>
        Title
        <input type="text" ng-model="tasks.title">

        ID
        <input type="text" ng-model="tasks.id">

        Type
        <select ng-model="tasks.type">
            <option value="" disabled selected></option>
            <option value="Job">Job</option>
            <option value="Maintenence">Maintenence</option>
            <option value="Verification">Verification</option>
        </select>

        <!-- This button opens a modal to select the recurrence -->
        <a class="btn modal-trigger" href="#modal4">Recurrence</a>

        <!-- This button adds the task to the list -->
        <a ng-click="add(tasks)" class="btn" type="submit" name="action">Add</a>
    </form>
</div>
```

Here's how I save the task in my .js file:

```
$scope.add = function(tasks)
{
    $scope.tasks.push
    ({
        'id': tasks.id,
        'title': tasks.title,
        'type': tasks.type,
        'recurrence_type': tasks.recurrence_type
    });

    localStorage.setItem('tasks',JSON.stringify($scope.tasks));
};
```

As you can see I'm saving the tasks in the local storage. This is only a temporary solution for testing purposes, the final version will save the tasks to a database.

Anyway, I also have to have a recurrence mechanism, hence that `tasks.recurrence_type` in my `$scope`, and the button to open the modal in the form.

Here's that modal:

```
<!-- Modal Structure -->
<div id="modal4" class="modal">
    <div class="modal-content">
        <form>
            Repeats:
            <select ng-model="tasks.recurrence_type">
                <option value="" disabled selected></option>
                <option value="Daily">Daily</option>
                <option value="Weekly">Weekly</option>
                <option value="Monthly">Monthly</option>
                <option value="Yearly">Yearly</option>
            </select>
        </form>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="modal-footer">
    <a href="#" class=" modal-action modal-close btn">Save</a>
</div>
```

**My question is: how do I save the recurrence type in that modal to the** `$scope.tasks.recurrence_type`**?**

Comment: the modal is under the `submitController` template?

Comment: `ng-model="tasks.title"` means you have a $scope.tasks object, but  `$scope.tasks.push` seems to be an array. So what it is?

Comment: @AranS Not right now, the modal is separated from the rest of the code in the .html file. But I can put the modal under the `SubmitController`. I'm gonna try that to see what happens.

Comment: @Medet Tleukabiluly It is an array, sorry about that, forgot to mention it. I have a `$scope.tasks = []`. The "title", "id" and "type" save properly, no problem. My only problem is saving the recurrence type.

Comment: take a look at angular-modal-service, it provides a simple and efficient way to handle modals, and it support bootstrap modals.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The scope of your modal and your template are different in this case. The solution to this problem is that you will have to use the `$rootScope.tasks`.

Comment: How do I use that? I tried simply putting `ng-model="$rootScope.tasks.recurrence_type">` but it didn't work. I also don't know if that option is being saved when I close the modal, that could also be the problem.

Comment: Change `$scope` to `$rootScope` everywhere in the controller. This will work

Comment: I'm supposed to change that in my JavaScript file, right? And leave my `ng-models` as they are right now?

Comment: Yes, you have to change your js

Comment: Okay, that worked! Is there any downsides of using `$rootScope` in my controller instead of `$scope`?

Comment: No there is no downside of this, but the thing is that it will make `tasks` accessible throughout the js

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest to use uibBootstraps $modal/$uibModal to open a modal, so you can control what happens with the scopes (shared scope or new scope for modal):
https://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/#modal

call from the html a angular method which opens the modal like this:

```
$modal.open({
    templateUrl: "path to modal html",
    scope: $scope 
});
```

I think in your current setting the scopes are different and the tasks object in the SubmitController does not get the recurrence_type